# PHP: Could we array an object?

Tags: php, arrays

I try to find out how to array some object inside, but hard to get a clear answer.  Get really headache. My program runs like this:

For more info: I attached original code of $df and $type at bottom.

Here is the code:

```
$arr1 = array('uncle1','uncle2','uncle3','uncle4','uncle5');
$arr2 = array('aunt1','aunt2','aunt3','aunt4','aunt5');
$arr3 = array('child1','child2','child3','child4','child5');

$un = 'uncle1'; 
$au = 'aunt1';
$ch = 'child1';

switch ($type){
case 'family':

$family1 = ($df->createElement($un,$au,$ch);

  //------- How I make an object base on many family at these arrays above, I try to foreach, but it can not run under function switch, It should has many objects like: $family1, $family2, $family3,.. with data from the array.

$df->sendFamily(array($family));
}
  //---------it should be like: $df>sendFamily(array($family1,$family2,....)) but I can not array an object
```

Here the original code of $df and $type:

```
if (isset($_GET['msg']) && ! empty($_GET['msg'])) 
 {
  $df = new Chatfuel(); 
  $type = strtolower($_GET['msg']);

//----- Begin an Chatfuel

   class Chatfuel
{
 protected $response = array();

  public function __construct($debug = FALSE)
  {
   if (( ! $debug) && ( ! isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) OR     strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Apache-HttpAsyncClient') === FALSE)) {
     exit;
   }
 }
public function __destruct()
  {
   if (count($this->response) > 0) {
  try {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('messages' => $this->response));
    exit;
  } catch (Exception $e) {

  }
}
 }
  public function createElement($title, $image, $subTitle, $buttons)
 {
  if ($this->isURL($image) && is_array($buttons)) {
  return array(
    'title'     => $title,
    'image_url' => $image,
    'subtitle'  => $subTitle,
    'buttons'   => $buttons
  );
}

return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Why not having a method in the class that returns an array of the related objects?

Comment: Thank Ofir. Of course, I will use foreach to get every data from an array. But  I stuck because I can not use a loop inside function createElement :(

Comment: You need to modify the $df class but you can. What's your code for that class?

Comment: It will take a long line, but i will try update on main question above

Comment: And chatfuel is a library you use? not your own written class?

Comment: Yes, And it runs well at other condition. With this function I mention above, It runs well but just only show 1 tab with 1 array data inside.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can array an object by following code:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($object as $key=>$value) {
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

But sadly I don't understand your code example at all. What is $df and where does $type come from?

Comment: Thank so much for your patient.  I add more info as your mention :

- $df: is an object to make a tab with content inside. It takes from a library and runs well.
- $type : is an object to get an event when user input. It takes from a library and runs well.